# How can I specify timezone with current_timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

How can I specify a timezone when calling the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function in Oracle? Note that I want to do it programmatically and not by setting some environment variable.

Comment: You may have to convert to string, change the tz offset, then convert back to timestamp with timezone - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm

Comment: You can't "specify a timezone" when calling `current_timestamp` - `current_timestamp` already has its own, very clearly specified timezone. Do you mean "convert the timestamp to a different time zone"? That's what MT0's answer does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AT TIME ZONE`:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_time,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS pst_time
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | UTC_TIME | PST_TIME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 18-SEP-21 20.02.58.762964 UTC | 18-SEP-21 13.02.58.762964 PST |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e40a65fd0706935f9ffaabea8f43118e)*